# Unable to update index for zk(http://www.zkoss.org) repository

Tags: maven, repository, m2eclipse, zk

In the pom.xml,I add the repository like this:


zk repository
http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2

when i update index for the zk repository,maven console said like this:
2/28/11 9:46:48 AM CST: Updating index zk repository|http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2
2/28/11 9:46:49 AM CST: Unable to update index for zk repository|http://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2

I tested on eclipse 3.6.2 with m2clipse, java1.6&java1.7,maven 3.0.2

Is there somebody have the same problem?

I have put this question in the zk forum,this link is:
http://www.zkoss.org/forum/listComment/15386/1/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any cause for worry.  `zkoss` repository is possibly not having a repository index file, which is requested by `m2eclipse`.

Comment: thank you,as you say, zkoss repository don't haveing a repository index file.  and we just explicit to define the dependency's right groupId,artifactId,version, then it works.